# The operatorManager does not exitst in the current context in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ado

I am executing this code but I am getting error in line

```
if (OperatorManager.IsOperatorAdmin(operatorID)).
```

Following are the libraries I have included

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

protected string GetRole()
{
    string role = string.Empty;
    int operatorID = 0;

    operatorID = int.Parse(Session["OperatorID"].ToString());

    if (OperatorManager.IsOperatorAdmin(operatorID))
        role = "Admin";
    else
        role = "User";

    return role;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add more info...

Comment: Is OperatorManager part of your project? If so, you're probably missing the using statement for the namespace it's defined in